# Can this foreach loop be improved?

Tags: c#

Can the below `foreach` loop be improved?  Since I use the same method twice, maybe use `continue` or `break`?

```
int? index = null;
int count = 0;
foreach (Break b in breaks)
{
    if (index.HasValue)
    {
        if (index == count)
            b.Remove();
    }
    else
    {
        b.Remove();
    }
    count++;
}
```

So I turned it into this:

```
foreach (Break b in breaks)
{
    if ((index.HasValue && index == count) || !index.HasValue)
    {
        b.Remove();
    }
    count++;
}
```

Which is the same.  Any other optimizations possible?

Comment: `index` is always `null`, so why not simply remove it?  `int count = 0; foreach(Break b in breaks { b.Remove(); count++ }`?  What value does having `index` serve?

Comment: I’ve always wondered why so many languages lack a Boolean “implies” operator `a ==> b` equivalent to `(a && b) || !a`, or perhaps `let x = a in (x && b) || !x` in the presence of side effects. Moreover, where’s my `let`-`in` expression?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about removing the loop at all like:

```
if (!index.HasValue)
{
     breaks.Clear();
}
else
{
     breaks.RemoveAt((int)index);
}
```

if you want/need to keep the loop, i would change your second way like:

```
foreach (Break b in breaks)
{
    if (!index.HasValue || index == count)
    {
        b.Remove();
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Leaving aside the question of why you have `index` in the first place, you don't need to check for nullity before you use a comparison operator. If you have

```
int x = whatever;
int? y = whatever;
bool b = x == y;
```

Then `b` will be `true` if `y` has a value equal to `x` and `false` otherwise. You don't have to say something like:

```
bool b = y.HasValue ? x == y.Value : false;
```

The compiler will generate that code on your behalf. This feature is called *lifting to nullable* and it applies to most of the operators in C#.

If the subject of how the compiler analyzes and generates code for lifted operators interests you, I wrote a long series of articles explaining it in detail. See

http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/